# error checkbox when show dialog

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a checkbox array

```
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="1" /><br />
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="2" /><br />
<input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="3" /><br />
```

This is my JavaScript

```
$(".create-daily").live("click",function(){
if ($( ".create-daily" ).attr("checked")){
$( "#form_input" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```

When I check the first checkbox, the dialog shows, when I check first checkbox and then check second checkbox, the second checkbox is shown...

...but when I check the second checkbox without having checked the first checkbox the dialog is not shown, can you help me?

How can I show the dialog when I check one of the checkboxes (for example chekbox number 3) without checking the first one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hiya `($( ".create-daily:checked")){` ghouls be used to check if checked or not your code i.e. HTML is not complete perhaps a jsfiddle, anyhow this should help, have a good one, cheerios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **this** to get the element that was actually clicked:

```
$(".create-daily").live("click",function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked")){
        $( "#form_input" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".create-daily").live("click",function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        $( "#form_input" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NFMDW/1/)***